# No response from potential PhD supervisor after Skype meeting

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding

Four weeks ago, I had a meeting over Skype with my potential PhD supervisor for an open PhD position in his group. He initially expressed interest in my work and asked me to arrange for two recommendation letters in order to know more about me and then later, we discussed about my current/past research works, my future plans and intricacies of his work for about 45 minutes over Skype. He had also specified that both of my letters were good and will discuss with his boss (his group leader) regarding my academic background and research experience. Finally he told that he had applied for a grant and will let me know once he gets to know about the outcome. Overall, the meeting went quite well. Since then, I haven't heard back from him. He also hasn't responded to a couple of my reminder emails. Should I be optimistic about this?

Comment: well, it is up in the air. No response might mean that there are no news yet to share.

Comment: If your employment is dependent on the supervisor getting their grant approved, then you realistically have about 25% of getting the position. The results of a grant usually come several months after submission.

Answer (score 3):

Call him or his assistant. Or drop by during his duty hours or after his lectures.

No, you shouldn't be optimistic, you should continue applying for other positions.

Comment: I spoke to him on Skype and the professor told me that he will be getting the funding shortly and will be posting the position in 1.5 months or so. He also added that around that time, I should resend my documents with updated information about my current work and CV.